# grid item is hidden when changing the grid-template-columns on media query

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have 2 of those meal description boxes:

```html
<div class="meal">
  <img
    src="img/meals/meal-1.jpg"
    alt="first meal"
    class="meal-img"
  />
  <div class="meal-content-box">
    <div class="meal-tags">
      <span class="meal-tag vegeterian">Vegeterian</span>
    </div>
    <p class="meal-title">Japanese Gyozas</p>
    <ul class="meal-attributes">
      <li class="meal-attribute">
        <ion-icon name="flame-outline" class="meal-icon"></ion-icon>
        <p><strong>650</strong> Calories</p>
      </li>
      <li class="meal-attribute">
        <ion-icon
          name="restaurant-outline"
          class="meal-icon"
        ></ion-icon>
        <p>NutriScore &reg; <strong>74</strong></p>
      </li>
      <li class="meal-attribute">
        <ion-icon name="star-outline" class="meal-icon"></ion-icon>
        <p><strong>4.9</strong> rating (537)</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this list

```html
<div class="works-with-list-box">
  <h2 class="heading-third">Works with any diet:</h2>
  <ul class="work-with-ul">
    <li class="work-with-li">
      <ion-icon
        name="checkmark-outline"
        class="work-with-list-icon"
      ></ion-icon>
      <span class="diet-item">Vegetarian </span>
    </li>
    <li class="work-with-li">
      <ion-icon
        name="checkmark-outline"
        class="work-with-list-icon"
      ></ion-icon>
      <span class="diet-item">Vegan </span>
    </li>
    <li class="work-with-li">
      <ion-icon
        name="checkmark-outline"
        class="work-with-list-icon"
      ></ion-icon>
      <span class="diet-item">Pescatarian </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

on default I have this grid for them

```css
grid-2-cols{
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
column-gap: 4.8rem
row-gap:6.4rem
}
```

and when using this code:

```css
@media (max-width: 36.75em) {
grid-2-cols{
grid-template-columns: 1fr
}
}
```

the second meal just get deleted or hidden as in this pictures
[normal grid without the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge4KH.png)
[second meal get deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCJil.png)

can anyone explain why this is happening? and how can I fix it

I tried changing the grid-template-columns and expecting a 3 rows grid of 2 meals and a list but got only 1 meal and a list (one of the meals got deleted)

Comment: Is the "works-with-list-box" also in the grid? Or just the two cards in the grid container?

Comment: it is in the grid, it basically span over the 2 columns in the second row

Answer (score 0):

I suggest wrapping the two meal cards inside one container to which apply the grid. And then wrap the container with the `.works-with-list-box` inside another container. Something like this:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 6.4rem;
}

.meals {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 4.8rem;
  row-gap: 6.4rem;
}

@media (max-width: 36.75em) {
  .meals {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="meals">
    <div class="meal">
      <h2>Meal #1</h2>
      <p>This is meal one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="meal">
      <h2>Meal #1</h2>
      <p>This is meal one</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="works-with">
    <h2 class="heading-third">Works with any diet:</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Vegetarian</li>
      <li>Vegan</li>
      <li>Pescatarian</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```